# Can't call a function from a menu

Tags: python

I am having trouble calling the functions. all of the functions that have been created work fine. I am just having trouble calling the functions from the menu. I am still pretty new to python so also if you see something that don't make sense please do tell me.

```
#function for lottery generator
def lottery_number_generator():
    import random
    lottoNumber = []

    for i in range(0,7):
        randNum = random.randint(0,9)
        lottoNumber.append(randNum)

    for i in range(0,7):
        print lottoNumber[i],

#function for number analysis
def number_analysis():
    total = 0.0
    average = 0.0
    numberInput = 0.0
    numbers = []

    print("Enter in a series of 20 numbers\n")

    for i in range(20):
        numberInput = input("Enter your %s number: " % (i+1))
        numbers.append(numberInput)
        total += numberInput
    average = total / 20

    print ("\nThe highest number is %.2f: " % max(numbers))
    print ("The lowest number is %.2f: " % min(numbers))
    print ("Your total is %.2f: " % total)
    print ("Your average is %.2f: " %average)

#function for rainfall calculator
def rainfall():
    totRain = 0.0
    average = 0.0
    totalRain = 0.0
    months = ["January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    rainFall = []
    for i in range(0,12):
        monthRain = input("Enter rainfall inches for %s: " % months[i])
        rainFall.append(monthRain)
        totalRain += monthRain

    average = float(totalRain / 12)

    for i in range(0,12):
        print ''
        print("Rainfall for %s is %i" %(months[i],rainFall[i]))

    print ("\nThe total rainfall was %.2f: " % totalRain)
    print ("The average rainfall is %.2f" % average)
    print ("The highest amount of rainfall was %.2f "% max(rainFall))
    print ("The lowest amount of rainfall was %.2f "% min(rainFall))

#function for total sales
def total_sales():
    day = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
    dailySales = []
    sales = 0.0
    totalSales = 0.0

    for i in range(0,7):
        sales = input("Enter sales for %s " % day[i])
        dailySales.append(sales)
        totalSales += sales    

    for i in range(0,7):
        print ("Sales for %s is %.2f:" % (day[i],dailySales[i]))
    print ("For a total of %.2f: " % totalSales)
def menu():
    print ("1. Play lottery number generator.\n2. Play number analysis.\n3. Play rainfall calculator.\n4. Play total sales calculator.\n5. Exit/Quit.")
    input()
def main():
    while True:
        if menu() == 1:
            lottery_number_generator()
        elif menu() == 2:
            number_analysis()
        elif menu() == 3:
            rainfall()
        elif menu() == 4:
            total_sales()
        elif menu() == 0:
            quit
        else:
            print ("\n Not a valid choice try AGAIN.")

#start of program


print ("Welcome, Please select which HW assignment you would like to view:\nPlease select which HW assignment to play by pushing the number.\n")

menu()
main()
```

Comment: I think you want to `return input()` in your menu function. Also you don't need to call `menu()` at the second last line in your code, just `main()` seems enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by umutto, you need to return the choice from `input()`:

```
def menu():
    print ("1. Play lottery number generator.\n2. Play number analysis.\n3. Play rainfall calculator.\n4. Play total sales calculator.\n5. Exit/Quit.")
    return input()
```

Then you probably want to get the choice only once per iteration and then test for its value:

```
def main():
    while True:
        choice = menu()
        if choice == 1:
            lottery_number_generator()
        elif choice == 2:
            number_analysis()
        elif choice == 3:
            rainfall()
        elif choice == 4:
            total_sales()
        elif choice == 0:
            quit
        else:
            print ("\n Not a valid choice try AGAIN.")

#start of program


print ("Welcome, Please select which HW assignment you would like to view:\nPlease select which HW assignment to play by pushing the number.\n")

main()
```

NOTE: depending on your python version you may need to be careful dealing with strings `"1"` or numbers `1` when you test the value of `choice`...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I now have it working.